# Fade In and Out on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The CSS styling for this fade in and out animation seems fine, but it is not reusable with javascript. Once the function performs once, it can not be triggered by button onClick again, what is the way around this?

```js
//removeClass
//addClass
```

```css
.elementToFadeInAndOut {
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
    animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
    opacity: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="animationfunction()">Button</button>
<div id="icon" class="elementToFadeInAndOut"></div>
```

Comment: Where is the `.animate()` function?

Comment: *"It's not reusable with javascript"* - because you didn't write js code.

Comment: @Kinduser is on -1 flags, better go and purchase more flags with your reputation currency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only need to have the button click add the class membership, wait until the animation is complete and then remove the class.

```js
var div = document.querySelector(".fade");
var btn = document.querySelector(".fadeButton");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  div.classList.add("elementToFadeInAndOut");
  // Wait until the animation is over and then remove the class, so that
  // the next click can re-add it.
  setTimeout(function(){div.classList.remove("elementToFadeInAndOut");}, 4000);
});
```

```css
.fade{
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    opacity:0;
}

.elementToFadeInAndOut {
    animation: fadeInOut 4s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInOut {
 0% { opacity:0; }
 50% { opacity:1; } 
 100% { opacity:0; } 
}
```

```html
<button class="fadeButton">Button</button>
<div class="fade"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, i needed help with the javascript. I couldn't get it to parse.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use jQuery for  functions 
here is the code for fade in and out effect for toggle button.
you can adjust the time by changing that (1000) in jQuery Thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button.btn').click(function(){
     $("div.elementToFadeInAndOut").fadeOut(1000);
          $("div.elementToFadeInAndOut").fadeIn(1000);
    });
    });
```

```css
.elementToFadeInAndOut {
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Button</button>
<div class="elementToFadeInAndOut"></div>
```

Comment: Fade in and out on a single click.